# Autosize css dropdown to fit it's largest element

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to make a dropdown for choosing from a list of items that always have a width of it's widest element. The selected item is the item that's always shown and other options are shown on hover.

It's a simple CSS dropdown, and ideally, I would like to see pure CSS solution. Since I'm using React and this dropdown is a component, a js solution would be acceptable (without using jQuery or other libraries if possible).

```js
const Dropdown = (props) => (
 <div className="dropdown">
   <div className="dropdown-item">{props.active}</div>
    <div className="dropdown-body">
      {props.items
        .filter(x => x !== props.active)
        .map(x => <div className="dropdown-item">{x}</div>)}
    </div>
 </div>
)

var items = [
 "abc", "abcdcdssd", "a"
]

ReactDOM.render(
 <div>Hello <Dropdown items={items} active={"abc"} /> world.</div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
)
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-item {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-body {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-body {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

In the example above, I would like for the `"abc"` element to have a width of the largest element `"abcdcdssd"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pure CSS Solution

A pure css solution would be to give your container a `width: auto` and use the `visibility` style instead of `display` on your items to hide them:

```js
const Dropdown = (props) => (
 <div className="dropdown">
   <div className="dropdown-item">{props.active}</div>
    <div className="dropdown-body">
      {props.items
        .filter(x => x !== props.active)
        .map(x => <div className="dropdown-item">{x}</div>)}
    </div>
 </div>
)

var items = [
 "abc", "abcdcdssd", "a"
]

ReactDOM.render(
 <div>Hello <Dropdown items={items} active={"abc"} /> world.</div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
)

var items = [
 "abc", "abcdcdssd", "a"
]

ReactDOM.render(
 <div>Hello <Dropdown items={items} active={"abc"} /> world.</div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
)
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: auto;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-item {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-body {
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-body {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

The caveat is that because the items are only hidden if you select the text your hidden items will be selected too.

### JS Solution

You can measure the width of the dropdown body after the initial render and apply it to the active dropdown item. To make this work you initially need to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` because only the width of hidden elements can be measured. You could hide them as soon as they have been measured initially.

The example below uses react hooks which requires a version `>16.8` but it can also be achieved with a class based component using `componentDidMount`.

```js
const {useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect} = React;

const Dropdown = props => {
    const bodyRef = useRef();
    const [bodyWidth, setWidth] = useState(null);
    const [itemsHidden, setItemsHidden] = useState(false);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setWidth(bodyRef.current.clientWidth);
        setItemsHidden(true);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{width: bodyWidth || 'auto'}} className="dropdown">
            <div className="dropdown-item">{props.active}</div>
            <div ref={bodyRef} className={`dropdown-body${itemsHidden ? ' hidden' : ''}`}>
                {props.items
                    .filter(x => x !== props.active)
                    .map((x, idx) => (
                        <div key={idx} className="dropdown-item">{x}</div>
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

var items = [
 "abc", "abcdcdssd", "a"
]

ReactDOM.render(
 <div>Hello <Dropdown items={items} active={"abc"} /> world.</div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
)
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-item {
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-body {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-body.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-body {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the react solution but I'm not sure how the `setWidth` or `setItemsHidden` are supposed to work. They aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: @MarošBeťko They are returned by the `useState` hooks. You need `react>=16.8` to use hooks.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you are using 2 states there basically, one for width and one for itemsHidden. I've implemented your solution into my project but the first element isn't taking the width of the widest element of the list for some reason.

Comment: @MarošBeťko If you share your code in a codesandbox I can have a look at it. You may just be missing something from my answer. Double check that you have the same code and css implemented.

Comment: When the `useLayoutEffect` callback is called the client width is 0. In the app, when this dropdown is first added it's not rendered and hidden under a `display: none` element.

Comment: @MarošBeťko Okay so if it is `0` that indicates the body div has no content. It is mandatory to initially render the elements displayed so that their width can be measured. That is why I only set them hidden by applying the `hidden` css class after the measurement. Also when dynamically updating the items you will have to apply the layout effect again. In my example it will only be run once after mounting the component.

Comment: and what if the dropdown has to be hidden at first? how can I update the width after it becomes visible?

Comment: @MarošBeťko I will update my answer with a more sophisticated example that can handle updating and edge cases as soon as I have the time for it. Probably in the evening.